# Libreoffice crash after updating when file dialog needs to appear

Tags: libreoffice, crash

After updating libreoffice using `sudo apt upgrade`, libreoffice crashes when saving or opening a file. Libreoffice was upgraded from 1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1.17.10.1 to 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.1. Running the new libreoffice from the terminal produced this error message when saving:

```
X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Major opcode: 42 (X_SetInputFocus)
  Resource id:  0x6201019
X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Major opcode: 42 (X_SetInputFocus)
  Resource id:  0x6201019
X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Major opcode: 42 (X_SetInputFocus)
  Resource id:  0x62001b1
X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Major opcode: 42 (X_SetInputFocus)
  Resource id:  0x62001b1
```

After rolling back to 1.5.4.1-0ubuntu1.17.10.1, the same crash occurs but without the error message printed out.

The rollback command was:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-core=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-calc=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-impress=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-kde=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-writer=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-base-core=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-math=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-pdfimport=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-style-breeze=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-style-tango=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-style-elementary=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-style-galaxy=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-style-oxygen=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-java-common=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-common=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-base=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-base-drivers=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-help-en-us=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 libreoffice-draw=1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1
```

Below is the full list of packages upgraded through `sudo apt update`:

```
$ find /var/lib/dpkg/info -name \*.list -mtime -3 | sed 's#.list$##;s#..*/##'
ure
libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-java-common
linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic
libreoffice-common
gcc-7-base:amd64
gcc-7-base:i386
libstdc++6:amd64
libstdc++6:i386
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic
libubsan0:amd64
libtsan0:amd64
libgomp1:amd64
linux-generic
libitm1:amd64
libatomic1:amd64
linux-image-generic
libasan4:amd64
liblsan0:amd64
libcilkrts5:amd64
linux-signed-image-4.13.0-36-generic
libmpx2:amd64
libquadmath0:amd64
linux-signed-generic
cpp-7
libcc1-0:amd64
linux-signed-image-generic
g++-7
libgfortran4:amd64
libgfortran-7-dev:amd64
gfortran-7
gcc-7
libobjc4:amd64
libobjc-7-dev:amd64
libgcc-7-dev:amd64
libstdc++-7-dev:amd64
libgcc1:amd64
libreoffice-base
libgcc1:i386
fonts-opensymbol
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
libpulsedsp:amd64
pulseaudio-utils
pulseaudio-module-gconf
libreoffice-core
libpulse-dev:amd64
pulseaudio
libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64
libreoffice-base-drivers
libpulse0:amd64
libreoffice-help-en-us
uno-libs3
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-kde
libreoffice-writer
python3-uno
libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-pdfimport
libreoffice-style-breeze
libreoffice-style-tango
libreoffice-style-elementary
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-style-oxygen
libwavpack1:amd64
linux-headers-4.13.0-36
fonts-crosextra-caladea
fonts-crosextra-carlito
fonts-linuxlibertine
fonts-sil-gentium
fonts-sil-gentium-basic
libreoffice-report-builder-bin
libreoffice
libreoffice-script-provider-python
libreoffice-librelogo
libreoffice-report-builder
libreoffice-script-provider-bsh
libreoffice-script-provider-js
libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
libreoffice-wiki-publisher
libreoffice-nlpsolver
libreoffice-ogltrans
linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-libc-dev:amd64
linux-tools-common
linux-tools-4.13.0-36
linux-tools-4.13.0-36-generic
linux-tools-generic
```

Apparently the error appears when attempting to perform an operation that requires a file dialog to appear.

Answer (score 1):

After running libreoffice with --backtrace, I found that it's an error with the KDE file dialogs. A workaround is to turn on "Libreoffice Dialogs" in Tools>Options>General, as described in [the bug thread.](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98776#c32)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by switching to "LibreOffice Fresh" from the Ubuntu PPA [libreoffice/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).